# Query dentro de un while (PHP, SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Os explico la pregunta, lo que necesito que se muestre es una tabla tipo esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los días si que los muestro bien, así como los nombres de los usuarios. Pero no se como hacer para mostrar los horarios.
Intenté haciendo una consulta que sólo buscara el fullname, y dentro del while, dentro de cada `<td></td>` meter otra consulta para saber el horario pero no me funcionó.

Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Muchas gracias

```
$user_id = $_GET["userid"];
$groupid = $_GET["group"];


echo('<table border="1">'."\n");
echo('<tr><th></th>');
$weekModifier = 0;
$date = new DateTime();

if($date->format('N') !== 1) {
    $date->sub(new DateInterval('P'. $date->format('N') . 'D'));
}

$interval = new DateInterval('P'.abs($weekModifier).'W');

if($weekModifier > 0) {
    $date->add($interval);
} else {
    $date->sub($interval);
}

for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    echo "<th>" . $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('d-m') . "</th>";
}

echo "</tr>";

$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT fullname, name FROM people, shifts WHERE group_id=$groupid AND shift_id IN (SELECT shift_id FROM shift_assigned WHERE (user_id=$user_id AND day_id=8))");

while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo(htmlentities($row['fullname']));
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo(htmlentities($row['name']));
    echo "</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Hola, ¿de donde obtienes la información de los horarios? dependiendo de eso supongo que tendrás que hacerlo con `explode()` y un `for`, con mas información tal vez te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Hola, la informacion la tengo en una tabla shift_assigned que tiene las siguientes columnas: shift_assigned_id (el indice de la tabla), user_id (identificador del usuario), day_id (identificador del dia), shift_id (identificador del horario). Entonces por ejemplo, para el dia 24, usuario Mark, tendría que obtener el shift_id 1.

Comment: Si puedes agrergar esa información en la consulta del `while` con un `group_concat()` podria ser de gran ayuda